# How to remove a single object from Array Properties in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a state like:

```
const initialFieldValue={
...............

photos:[]
.........

}

const [state, setState] = useState(initialFieldValue);
```

Then I was pushing some object one by one through `onClick` function like that:

```
const handlePush=()=>{
     state.photos.push({
        fieldId: Math.random(), 
        file: file , /// from upload file
      });
    }
}
```

**Now I want to remove those object one by one onClick function like**

```
const handleRemove=(fieldId )=>{
    const tableDoc = [...state.photos];
    tableDoc.splice(
      tableDoc.findIndex(value => value.fieldId === fieldId),
      1,
    );
    state.photos = tableDoc;
}
```

Comment: There is not really any react here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution:

Change this line

```
state.photos = tableDoc;
```

to

```
setState({...state, photos: tableDoc});
```

---

### Refactor code:

```
const newPhotos = state.photos.filter(value => value.fieldId !== fieldId);
setState(prevState => ({...prevState, photos: ...newPhotos }));
```

---

### Note:

1. Don't mutate data in `React Js`: The same as `handleRemove` method, you shouldn't mutate data directly, please do something like this in `handlePush`

```
const newPhoto = {fieldId: Math.random(),file: file};
setState(prevState => ({...prevState, photos: [...prevState.photos, newPhoto]}));
```

2. Keep in mind that, from [`reactjs.org`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) docs say that:

> Unlike the `setState() method found in class components`, `useState` **does
> not automatically merge update objects**. You can **replicate** *this
> behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread
> syntax:*

```
setState(prevState => {
  // Object.assign would also work
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [above solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950214/9071943), You can try all in a single line (no need to `spread`, `findIndex`, and `splice`)

```
setState({...state, photos: state.photos.filter(value => value.fieldId !== fieldId)});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks Everyone for trying to solution for me . Everyone is right. but I can modification like that:**

```
//Old
const handlePush=()=>{
     state.photos.push({
        fieldId: Math.random(), 
        file: file , /// from upload file
      });
    }
}

//New

handleChange =()=>{
setState({
      ...state,
      photos: [...state.photos, { 
        fieldId: Math.random(), 
        file: file , /// from upload file 
      }],
    });
}
```

**then Remove function:**

```
//old
const handleRemove=(fieldId )=>{
    const tableDoc = [...state.photos];
    tableDoc.splice(
      tableDoc.findIndex(value => value.fieldId === fieldId),
      1,
    );
    state.photos = tableDoc;
}
//New
  const handlePhotoRemove = fieldId => {
    const tabPhotos = [...state.photos];
    tabPhotos.splice(
      tabPhotos.findIndex(value => value.fieldId === fieldId ),
      1,
    );
    setState({
      ...state,
      photos: tabPhotos,
    });
  };
```

***It is successfully done!!***

**thanks. Plz tell me if have any easy solutions**